# Sort flat file array

Tags: php, sorting, flat-file

I'm trying to sort data alphabetically by the COMPANY NAME from a flat file.  I was thinking that a simple sort would handle this, but I was wrong.  I now think that I need to use `usort` and `cmp` and then create another temp array. How can I accomplish this?

This is my current code.

```
$data_file = fopen($data_file_url, "r");
fgets($data_file); // IGNORE FIRST LINE IN FLATFILE - column names
while (!feof($data_file) ) {
    $data_lines = fgets($data_file);
    $data_ele = explode('|', $data_lines);

    $company_name = $data_ele[0];
    $section = $data_ele[1];
    $category = $data_ele[2];
    $service = $data_ele[3];
    $service = substr_replace($service,"",-1); // trim last char
}
```

Comment: Please show a preview for `$data_file_url`.

Comment: It would be much more efficient to sort the data before writing the file rather than re-sorting it every time it is read.

Answer (score 1):

You should first store all elements in a big array and afterwards sort it using a callback:

```
$data_file = fopen($data_file_url, "r");
fgets($data_file); // IGNORE FIRST LINE IN FLATFILE - column names

$companies = array();
while (!feof($data_file) ) {
    $data_lines = fgets($data_file);
    $data_ele = explode('|', $data_lines);

    $row = array();
    $row['company_name'] = $data_ele[0];
    $row['section'] = $data_ele[1];
    $row['category'] = $data_ele[2];
    $row['service'] = $data_ele[3];
    $row['service'] = substr_replace($row['service'],"",-1); // trim last char

    $companies[] = $row;
}

usort($companies, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['company_name'], $b['company_name']);
});
```

Please note: I'm using an anonymous function, introduced in PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: In my original code, I would print the value like this:  echo $company - - - How do I print the new value?

Comment: (*There is a typo in the code:  "$$" in the substr_replace.)  But even after fixing this, I still receive an error when running this code... somewhere in the usort function.  Any ideas?

Comment: which PHP version are you running? You need at least 5.3.0 for the anonymous function. to debug you should do a `print_r` just before the `usort` and check if the array looks as it should

Answer (score 0):

I would imporove upon Beats answer only by using the company name as a key in the array.

If you have multiple entries per company have a sub array.

By using the key as array it is already indexed when inserted.

I believe its faster.

You could also use `fgetcsv` here, which is also probably a little faster.